# Bootstrap not updating background image

Tags: html, css, nginx

I'm working on a bootstrap page on localhost, and everything is updating when reloaded, except the background picture. I have tried changing the URL of the background picture and even removing it completely from the /img folder and it still loads it in my browser. Is there some kind of caching going on? How can it still load an image that isn't even available in that folder?

Comment: yes. there is some kind of caching going on. clear the browsers cache with ctrl+shift+r or cmd+shift+r

Comment: Yup that did it, thanks